# Unlink Dropbox account from command line?

Tags: lubuntu, dropbox

Dropbox was successfully installed on a netbook running Lubuntu 16.04 - that is, there is a Dropbox folder that contains files that are synced across multiple devices.

Unfortunately, there is no Dropbox icon in the system tray, nor is there an accessible menu to "sign out" of Dropbox.  How can this device be unlinked from the Dropbox account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [official Dropbox command line interface (CLI)](http://web.archive.org/web/20190123060651/http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) that can help you.

To unlink your Dropbox account you can follow these [instructions](http://web.archive.org/web/20180705015441/http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment#Unlink_Relink_Dropbox_account) (without relinking your account after): `$ dropbox stop $ mv ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox.old`. Basically it just stop Dropbox and move/rename your Dropbox folder (`~/.dropbox`) into a backup folder (`~/.dropbox.old`) that can be removed if it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Next time please put the code in the answer. The site you linked to is now down.

Comment: I have updated the links and explicitly inserted the terminal commands.